# Android/OSX - Using NodeJS and Phonegap, Speak over Bluetooth

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, bluetooth, coffeescript

I'm attempting to make a small app that communicates over Bluetooth on OSX 10.10.1 (will eventually be Linux) and my Android (Nexus 5, 5.0.1).

On OSX, I'm running NodeJS 0.10.35 with [bluetooth-serial-port](https://github.com/eelcocramer/node-bluetooth-serial-port). A simple script I put together looks like this from an example I found.

```
btSerial = new (require("bluetooth-serial-port")).BluetoothSerialPort()

address = 'bc-f5-ac-54-4d-ba'

btSerial.findSerialPortChannel address, ((channel) ->
  console.log channel
  console.log "Connecting..."
  btSerial.connect address, channel, (->
    console.log "connected"

    btSerial.write new Buffer("Hello There\n", "utf-8"), (err, bytesWritten) ->
      console.log err if err

    btSerial.on "data", (buffer) ->
      console.log buffer.toString("utf-8")

    btSerial.on "failure", (err) ->
      console.log err

    btSerial.on "closed", () ->
      console.log 'disconnected'

  ), (err) ->
    console.log (err)
    console.log "cannot connect"

  # close the connection when you're ready
  # btSerial.close()

), ->
  console.log "found nothing"
```

On my android, I'm using AppGyvers Supersonic/SteroidsJS with the [BluetoothSerial Phonegap plugin](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial). I've created a custom scanner build so it includes the plugin. Here's just some quick things I put together to make testing a bit easier when using the dev console.

```
bt = {}

bt.connect = ->
  bluetoothSerial.connect "00:02:72:CD:62:2A", (success) ->
    console.log 'btConnect: Success'
    console.log success
  , (failed) ->
    console.log 'btConnect: Failed'
    console.log failed   

bt.disconnect = ->
  bluetoothSerial.disconnect()    

bt.isConnected = ->
  bluetoothSerial.isConnected (success) ->
    console.log 'btIsConnected: Success'
    console.log success
  , (failed) ->
    console.log 'btIsConnected: Failed'
    console.log failed  

bt.list = ->
  bluetoothSerial.list (success) ->
    console.log 'btList: Success'
    console.log success
  , (failed) ->
    console.log 'btList: Failed'
    console.log failed  

bt.write = ->
  bluetoothSerial.write "Hello From Android!", (success) ->
    console.log 'btWrite: Success'
    console.log success
  , (failed) ->
    console.log 'btWrite: Failed'
    console.log failed 

bt.subRaw = ->
  bluetoothSerial.subscribeRawData (success) ->
    console.log 'btSubRaw: Success'
    console.log success
  , (failed) ->
    console.log 'btSubRaw: Failed'
    console.log failed

bt.sub = ->
  bluetoothSerial.subscribeRawData '\n', (success) ->
    console.log 'btSub: Success'
    console.log success
  , (failed) ->
    console.log 'btSub: Failed'
    console.log failed

window.bt = bt
```

Now, here's where I get stuck. I need these applications to essentially speak to each other (I want to send objects back and forth). At the moment I can get both devices to connect from either or, and even have both establish the connection at the same, but in all situations neither the "on data" in NodeJS or subscribe on Steroids fire. I've confirmed both with code and in OSX prefs that the connection is active, but still stuck.

Sidenotes, if I had to pick for future which device I'd like to establish the connection, it would be NodeJS/OSX.

Any help on this is appcrieated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you finished that project? It's public or open source?

Comment: Both sides are clients that try to connect to a Bluetooth server. To make it work one side should listen for incoming connection. The bluetooth-serial-port module only implements the client side so to use that you should have your program on Android listen for incoming connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I couldn't get the two to speak. However, the following works for reading and writing from node using [serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) (OSX 10.0.1). Either OSX or the phone can make the initial connection and it'll both work, but if OSX initializes it then Steroids will have to check if a connection exists before continuing.

```
SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port",
  baudrate: 9600
)

serialPort.on "open", ->
  console.log "open"
  serialPort.on "data", (data) ->
    console.log "data received: " + data

    serialPort.write data, (err, results) ->
      console.log "err " + err if err
      console.log "results " + results
```